# What is the '?' in a href when calling a php script?

Tags: php, html, scripting, href

I've seen a ? followed by an id when calling a php in an href. I've been researching, but can't seem to find a straight answer (probably using the wrong terminology)

```
<a href='page2.php?id=2>
```

What is the '?' followed by the id here? Any explanation would be appreciated, I'm new to php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to pass data within a url from page to page. When the page loads, PHP can access that data with a call like this.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Then PHP can use this data for its own purposes.

You can string together data as well like...

```
?id=2&name=james
```

And again access the data with a call like...

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

This is how forms work except when you POST a form, the values are hidden in the url and you retrieve the data like...

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

But if your PHP doesn't know if the data will be a POST or a GET, you can use

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

Which can grab the data from either a POST or GET.

Comment: Thanks for the help and examples, really clarified things. I'll probably be able to make some of my scripts more efficient now with this knowledge.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help you out! :)

Answer (score 1):

**GET** data comes from the URL itself, and will typically follow the name of the script file in the URL. The start of GET data is indicated with a question mark (?).

[GET  POST  REQUEST METHOD](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)